# Rails Devise Sign in and Sign Up redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, routes

I'm trying to get some changes I had a contractor make working on my local and I can't seem to get past this error, mainly because I am not air tight in my understanding of how this works hence the hiring of the contractor.

Anyway, I asked that he redirect users to their profile page on sign up and sign in (I'm using Devise) and I get these two errors

Sign in and Sign Up-

```
undefined method `profile_path' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x007fa992493f48>
```

The application controller-

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    profile_path(id: resource.profile_name)
  end
end
```

My Routes-

```
Goldengoal::Application.routes.draw do
  # get "profiles/show", :as => 'profile'
  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do #this is how you seperate between player and parent what they can see
    get 'register', to: "devise/registrations#new", as: :register
    get 'login',    to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :login
    get 'logout',   to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :logout
  end

  root :to => 'front#index'

  resources :users, path: '', controller: 'profiles', only: [:show] do
    resources :players
    resources :logistics
    resources :notes
  end
```

What am I missing here? Could it have been an issue in getting the latest changes from Github? He said everything was working fine on his machine. I'm fairly lost here.

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

I ran rake routes and in the method controller I changed it from

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    profile_path(id: resource.profile_name)
end
```

to:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_path(id: resource.profile_name)
end
```

and everything seems to be working fine in the browser. Can anyone comment that this is indeed the correct fix and the contractor just failed to change this?

Comment: This is the correct fix. While you have a `ProfilesController`, the route is defined as `resources :users`, which will give you a `user_path` helper. This would be less confusing if the controller name matched the resource in question.